# How to use a grid in the XAML Mainwindow to another class in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, oop

In the code behind of a main window of a WPF project, there is a grid with a specific name in XAML page as follow:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="PnlGraphics" Margin="5"></Grid>
```

In another class (e.g. ClsChart) in a function, I need to set this grid value.

Here is the piece of code that uses that grid name in clsChart class:

```
PnlGraphics.Children.Add(host)
```

I tried many things as below, but my problem has not been resolved yet.

1- I made an object from the main class and tried to use that to get access to the grid name. But in practice, it gives an error when I run the program!

```
Dim mainClass1 as new mainClass = new mainClass()
mainclass1.pnlGraphics.Children.Add(host)
```

2- I made a panel control in the ClsChart class and tried to fill the grid in the main class.

In the clsChart class:

```
 Private _panel1 As Panel
 Public Property Panel1 As Panel
    Get
        Return _panel1
    End Get
    Set(value As Panel)
        _panel1 = value
    End Set
 End Property
 Panel1.Children.Add(host)
```

and in the main:

```
ChartObject.Panel1 = PnlGraphics
```

3- I changed the grid modifier to the public.

Any thought on this?

Comment: *I tried many things*...Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: *"I **need** to use this grid"* -- I doubt that you really do. Can you explain why? What is this other class doing with it?

Comment: I have updated my question and counted 3 different things that my colleagues told me.    For more clarification, clsChart class draws the chart and I need to put that chart in that grid after I instantiate it in the main.

Comment: @Ehsan This communicates nothing: *"I made an object from the main class and tried to use that to get access to the grid name"*. Nobody on earth could possibly figure out what the actual code was, or even what you intended for it to do. **"Show what you tried" means show the code**. *"tried to fill the grid in the main class*" ?

Comment: If this is actually WPF, what your'e doing is very wrong and a bad idea. Again, please explain what your actual goal is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added some lines of my code. Please let me know if it is more readable or not?

Comment: @Ehsan All too clear, thanks.

Comment: If you need to access to the grid I can direct you. but I think what you need is accessing to the data not control. right?

Comment: I want to get access to the grid for now. But in the future probably I may need to access the data as well. Could you explain both to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate an `clsChart` object in your main class and pass the grid as parameter to the constructor (e.g. `clsChart c = new clsChart(grid)`). In the constructor you assign `grid` to some member variable of type `Grid` and use it as needed.

Comment: When I create a constructor in the main to pass the grid, it gives an error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll) and prevents me from doing that. 
 Sub New(grid As Grid)

        pnlGraphics = grid

    End Sub

Comment: How am I supposed to diagnose the error without the code?

Comment: You answered this long time ago, but now I see how easily you answered the question! I tried to modify my question with the hope that it might be useful for somebody else. Thanks anyway!